# Are ruby jit compilation results retained on Heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, jit

I am currently running a ruby script through Heroku Scheduler.

Since any changes to the [ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) are discarded after the [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) stops, was wondering if `ruby —jit` has any (positive) effect while used in the Heroku Scheduler environment.

Are compilation results retained and re-used as intended in subsequent runs?

Comment: "_in subsequent runs_" Do you mean of your one-off dyno? No. Do you mean subsequent method calls within the existing dyno? Yes. For example, if your app calls `1000.times { ''.empty? }` then sure, because you're repeatedly calling a method that is optimized by the jit. But if your app is dead-simple and runs very quickly you're probably not going to see any improvement. You should be using something like New Relic or another APM product to measure it directly. Just guessing at whether it's better or not isn't a good idea.

Comment: I meant in following-up runs of my one-off dyno. The ephemeral file system is self-explanatory so I guessed—jit not to be effective. Still Heroku may consider to add this specialized form of compiled ruby scripts persistency to the platform.

Comment: @WuMing2 "following-up runs", "one-off dyno" - these are mutually exclusive :)

Comment: “scheduled runs” of “one-off dyno” is more precise. But you are teasing me :)